# How to write a string (send) stimulus markers in e-prime for correct and incorrect responses

Tags: string, matlab, object-test-bench

Hello I need help with sending an alphanumeric marker when presenting a stimulus. I have set the port for communication and already have successfully sent markers to another program.

My wish now is to send markers if stimuli are correct or incorrect. So for example if stimulus is correct send marker "1" and if stimulus is incorrect send marker "0". I need to understand how  in-line script does this and what to write in the in-line script for it to perform the function specified.

Thank you in advance!!!

Juan

Comment: It's hard to tell what your question actually is. Do you have some code that you could include to make it clearer? What do you mean by "send marker?" Print to screen? Send over a serial port?

Comment: I don’t think MATLAB uses the BASIC programming language, does it?

Comment: When I refer to markers I mean TimeStamps. No Jerry my question is not about that but, the programme that I need to write on is based on Basic; then Matlab will be recieving stimuli 'markers' for target accuracy detection. For instance: stimuli appear, subject response then matlab recieves marker on eeg printing.